# CopyAsync in parallel?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm currently copying some files from my `Assets` into my `LocalStorage` folder.

What I'm doing is working but I was wondering if there was a way to make that part run in parallel :

```cs
foreach (StorageFile f in files)
{
    await f.CopyAsync(postes);
}
```

I tried something like that but of course it's not working because `CopyAsync` is not returning a `Task` and can not be cast to a `Task` :

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (StorageFile f in files)
{
    var task = (Task)f.CopyAsync(postes);
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll();
```

Complete code :

```cs
public async Task loadDefaultPosteInformationAsync()
{
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFolder postes = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Postes");

    StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFolder assets = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\Postes");
    var files = await assets.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (StorageFile f in files)
    {
        await f.CopyAsync(postes);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for the [`AsTask` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.astask).

Comment: It appears to be a good solution, but when I type `Task.AsTask()` it don't finds the method.

Comment: It's an extension method on `IAsyncOperation`, not a method on `Task`. It should be made available by referencing the [System.Windows.WindowsRuntime package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/) and using the `System` namespace (if for some reason that wasn't already the case). Then `f.CopyAsync(postes).AsTask()` should compile. (Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: Oh yeah now it works, thanks a lot :)